# how to use proportion information within a column to select specific rows (participants) in R

Tags: r, select, filter, group-by, dplyr

I need help to select a subset of participants on my dataset.
I have a varied number of observations (rows) per participant. I want to work with only those participants who make less than 5% of Conventional_response_code = F, and those with the biggest proportion of Conventional_response_code = S.

```
participant Test_word    Regular_response    Conventional_response_code   PPT
   <chr>       <chr>        <chr>               <chr>                      <dbl>
 1 BM0289      ambulance    NA                  N                             92
 2 BM0289      bat          NR                  NR                            92
 3 BM0289      beard        man with a mustache D                             92
 4 BM0289      binoculars   NA                  N                             92
 5 BM0289      bride        wedding dress       PP                            92
 6 BM0289      cannon       gun                 M                             92
 7 BM0289      cheerleaders NA                  N                             92
 8 BM0289      chimney      NA                  N                             92
 9 BM0289      dinosaur     NR                  NR                            92
10 BM0289      dragon       NR                  NR                            92
```

I managed to create a proportion table in which I can see this information:

```
###Number of errors per participant (raw numbers)
proptable<-xtabs(formula= ~ participant + Conventional_response_code, data=data)

###proportion of errors per participant (row)
proptable<- (round(100*prop.table(proptable, margin=1), digits=2))
head(proptable)

                    Conventional_response_code
participant Adm E    AN     B     D     F     M M-F-F M-F-U   M-N M-N-A M-N-N    MO     N    NR     O    PP  PP-F  PP-N Prima     S   S-F S-F-F
     BM0289  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.99  2.97 18.81  0.99  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.99  2.97 23.76 29.70  0.00  6.93  0.00  0.00  0.00  8.91  0.00  0.00
     BM0601  0.95  5.71  0.00  9.52 20.00  4.76  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  2.86 20.95  3.81  7.62  1.90  0.00  0.00  3.81 18.10  0.00  0.00
     LD0001  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  7.69  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 61.54  7.69  0.00 15.38  0.00  0.00  0.00  7.69  0.00  0.00
     LD0002  0.00  0.00  0.00 27.50  0.00 12.50  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  2.50  2.50 20.00  5.00  7.50  0.00  0.00  0.00 17.50  0.00  0.00
     LD0003  2.27  0.00  4.55 13.64 27.27  2.27  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  2.27 29.55  2.27  0.00  2.27  0.00  0.00  0.00 13.64  0.00  0.00
     LD0004  4.67  0.00  0.00 11.21  4.67 12.15  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.93  0.93  0.93 20.56 14.95  0.93  4.67  0.00  0.00  0.93 19.63  0.00  0.00
           Conventional_response_code
participant S-F-U   S-N S-N-A S-N-N     U
     BM0289  0.00  0.00  1.98  0.99  0.00
     BM0601  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
     LD0001  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
     LD0002  0.00  0.00  5.00  0.00  0.00
     LD0003  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
     LD0004  0.00  0.00  0.93  1.87  0.00
>
```

but that creates a separate table. How do I use the information from this proportion in my own dataset (data) and select those participants that satisfy the conditions I need:

- the number of F values in the Conventional_response_code column should be under 5%
- the proportion of S values in the Conventional_response_code column should be the highest

Thank you!!

Comment: You can filter your `proptable` to get participant ids and then filter the original data. E.g. ```participants <- proptable %>% filter(F < 5) %>% pull(participant)``` ```data %>% filter(participant %in% participants)```. I cannot test my solution, because you do not provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I'm not sure what you mean by the "S values should be the highest".

Answer (score 0):

Even though you already have found a way to put together your `proptable` dataframe, I would imagine it is easier to start a solution from the initial `participant` table, since you want to compare the frequencies of `Conventional_response_code`.

```
library(dplyr)

participants.filtered <- participant %>%
  count(participant, Conventional_response_code) %>%
  group_by(participant) %>%
  mutate(freq = n/sum(n)) %>%
  filter(any(Conventional_response_code == 'F' & freq < 0.05)) %>%
  arrange(desc(freq)) %>%
  filter(Conventional_response_code == 'S', row_number() == 1) %>%
  pull(participant) %>%
  unique()
```

Does that help?